# Как получить ссылку у тега <a> в BeautifulSoup если у него нет класса python

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть тег a , находящийся в div с классом "v1Nh3 kIKUG" , как я могу получить доступ к этому тегу a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ознакомтесь с [документацией](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
soup = BeautifulSoap(r.text, 'html.parser')
tag_a = soup.find('div', class_='v1Nh3 kIKUG').a
```